# PartCover generates empty output file

Tags: nant, teamcity, partcover

I'm currently trying to create a Nant task for our TeamCity setup so that our UnitTests are ran through Gallio and covered by PartCover. The task looks like this:

```
<!-- UnitTest Configuration -->
  <!-- ====================== -->
  <!-- This configuration runs the tests through Gallio with MbUnit together with
       PartCover to get the results of the test together with the coverage results 
  -->
  <target name="unitTest">      
        <echo message="Unittesting ${AssemblyToTest}"/>
        <exec program="${Paths.Tools}\PartCover\Partcover.exe" failonerror="true">
          <arg line="--target &quot;${Paths.Tools}\Gallio\Gallio.Echo.exe&quot;" />
          <arg line="--target-work-dir ${AssemblyToTestLocation}"/>
          <arg line="--target-args /r:Local &quot;${AssemblyToTest}&quot;" />
          <arg line="--include &quot;[${Tests.TestedAssemblyName}]*&quot;" />
          <arg line="--output ${Paths.Output}\Coverage.xml" />
        </exec>
  </target>
```

The tests are running, we can see this in TeamCity, and a Coverage.xml file is generated, but empty. There's only a single line in it.

Output of the variables:-

- ${Paths.Tools} : C:\Robinson\Trunk\
- ${Tests.TestedAssemblyName} : Name of the DLL
- ${AssemblyToTestLocation} : Path to the DLL

Am I missing something?

***EDIT***
The TeamCity application is running on a Windows Server 2003 R2 Server, and all the build-agents performing the work are currently running on Windows XP Systems, all 32bit installations.

Comment: Is your Teamcity server running on 32bit or 64bit Windows?

Comment: Our TeamCity is running on a Windows Server 2003 R2 server, so I assume it to be 32bit, as its nowhere mentioned. The tests are beeing ran on build-agents which are currently all Windows XP 32bit systems

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET 4 and 3.5, but the goal is going for .NET 4 only

Comment: And the version of PartCover that you're using?

Comment: latest from the github project, n oidea on the version

Comment: Sounds like PartCover .NET 4. Which is important, because the previous versions did not work with .NET 4 and would result in empty report files. However , this probably isn't the issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we covered this issue in https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4/issues/46

and the solution was along the lines of

--include [${Tests.TestedAssemblyName}*]* ?

Comment: we did :)
And we even drove the discussion & solution further at http://www.russellallen.info/post/Automating-Test-Coverage-with-PartCover-NUnit-and-Nant.aspx